# How can i add quasar framework to my vue cli project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework, quasar

i am a newer too vue js and  i create a vue project called my-practise-vue by using vue-cli.

Now I want to use quasar component and styles. I installed quasar by using this command

```
npm install quasar@2 --save
```

And i saw quasar framework in the node modules folder.But when i use a quasar component like Avatar or skeleton, i didn't see any effect.

How can i do ? I must add a link of quasar css and quasar component in my main.js file ?

can you help me please ?

Comment: Have you tried the official guideline? https://quasar.dev/start/vue-cli-plugin

Comment: If you are going to make a new project from scratch, please give up the Vue-CLI and switch to Quasar-CLI using Vite.

Comment: hi @Mr.R, i have do vue add quasar but i have this error:   Installing vue-cli-plugin-quasar...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for postcss-rtl@^3.5.3.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.. How can i do

Comment: To add Quasar into a Vue CLI, you should run `vue add quasar` according to documents. There is no need to install the Quasar@2 package.